# Run the same VBA macro on different excel files with a button on my custom Ribbon

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a VBA macro and need to perform the same tasks on multiple different files. Ideally i'd like to create a button on my Ribbon and execute the tasks with the click of a button. How do I make the macro available to multiple files and execute the tasks using the data from a newly opened worksheet? I've added the macro to a PERSONALS.xlsb file and can see the macro available every time I open Excel, but the macro only executes the tasks on the PERSONALS.xlsb file, not the newly opened file.

```
Sub Export_Files()

  Dim sExportFolder, sFN
  Dim rDiscription As Range
  Dim rHTMLcode As Range
  Dim oSh As Worksheet
  Dim oFS As Object
  Dim oTxt As Object

  'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
  'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
  sExportFolder = "C:\Users\bhinton\Desktop\ActionTags"
  Set oSh = Sheet1

  Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

  For Each rDiscription In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("C").Cells
      Set rHTMLcode = rDiscription.Offset(, 6)

      'Add .txt to the article name as a file name
      sFN = rDiscription.Value & ".html"
      Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
      oTxt.Write rHTMLcode.Value
      oTxt.Close
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If an answer is helpful, please click the check mark on the left to mark it as the answer. If it is a good answer you can vote it up too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Set oSh = Sheet1
```

You need to use

```
Set oSh = ActiveSheet
```

Using ActiveSheet means that the code will use the newly opened workbook and the active sheet which I think is what you want.

Or if you always want Sheet1 of the currently active workbook, you can do this:

```
Set oSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: Thanks! This simple change made everything work as intended. I now have a button on my ribbon with a little piglet icon that executes the task whenever pressed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to prompt the user to select files then iterate through them:

```
Option Explicit
Sub OpenFilesAndIterate()

Dim DataDialog As FileDialog
Dim NumFiles As Long, Counter As Long
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MySheet As Worksheet

'prompt the user to select data files
Set DataDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With DataDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Please pick the files you'd like to operate on:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With

'assign the number of files selected for an easy loop boundary
NumFiles = DataDialog.SelectedItems.Count

'check to see if the user clicked cancel
If NumFiles = 0 Then Exit Sub

'Start looping through and do work
For Counter = 1 To NumFiles
    Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(DataDialog.SelectedItems(Counter))
    Set MySheet = MyWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    '
    'insert your code to operate on worksheet here
    '
    MyWorkbook.Save
    MyWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next Counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the options for Excel, click on Customize Ribbon. Above the list of things you can add there should be a dropdown box where you can select Macros. The list should then be populated with macros to add to your ribbon!

[image: Customizing the Ribbon]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the questions wasn't how to create a button, but rather how to utilize the macro across multiple different excel files once opened. A button just was my way of making it easy to execute.